# Refresh DataTable after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table with several columns loaded from the DB, I applied a filter to be able to load only the wo's closed, but when I apply to look for the wo's open nothing appears.

Maybe I have to do a reload in the datatable?

```js
$("#close").click(function(){
  var table = $('#todolist').DataTable();
  table.columns([2,3]).search("W.O.", "Close").draw();
});

$("#open").click(function(){
  var table = $('#todolist').DataTable();
  table.columns([2,3]).search("W.O.", "open").draw();
});
```

I tried to use `$('#pedidos').DataTable().ajax.reload();` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you seeing an errors in the console of the browser?

Comment: @JoelEtherton i got no erro from console or browser, i just think i need to make a refreshe on datatable but i don't know how

Comment: What is `open` and `close` used for? The second argument of `.search()` is actually a boolean: https://datatables.net/reference/api/search

Comment: @Terry the 'open' and 'close' is the open workorders and closed workorders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#open").click(function(){
  $("#todolist").DataTable().draw();
});
```

Use this function wherever you want to refresh the datatable.

Comment: didn't wok, the table still empty

Comment: Also is this open and close click function is working? check by doing alert or console in it.

Comment: no error coming from your code, yes the click is working, tha data search is implemented